# How to change the default font for Bless hex editor?

Tags: fonts, mono

`bless` seems slightly better to me then `ghex`, but it has this ugly default font I can't stand.

My system monospaced font is set to Droid Sans Mono, size 9 and `bless` uses Courier New, size 12. It's too big and not preferred here, but can't find way to change it. Don't know if this is because it's mono developed, don't praise that either, but I searched in all folders where `bless` is "unpacked":

```
/usr/lib/bless  
/usr/share/bless
```

and then:

```
~/.config/bless
```

There is no file where font is defined.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Although font can't be set from editor, `bless` comes with extensive help system, where it is explained that, font tag can be used as child element in `<display>` tag in `bless` layouts configuration files (w/o example)

In action:

- open `/usr/share/bless/bless-default.layout`
- on every `<area>` element add `<display>` child element (if not defined) in which child element `<font>` can be set

---

```
<area type="ascii">
    <display><font>Droid Sans Mono 9</font></display>
</area>
```